# Math using array skips "16"

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I'm writing this code where you type in a number and a number that is divisible by it and all the numbers before it (the least common multiple of 1,2, ...n) . I thought I had it until I noticed something odd. When you put in an input of 16, you get 720720. This is correct (720720 is divisible by all the numbers up to 16). But, when you put in 17, the output is 6126120. This is wrong. I found that every number before 16 is off. Why is this so? All I know is that 6126120 is half of what is supposed to be the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The + Operator</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get your Answer!</button>

    <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var number = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

            var lowEnd = 1;
            var highEnd = number;
            var arr = [];
            while (lowEnd <= highEnd) {
                arr.push(lowEnd++);
            }

            function lcm_more_than_two_numbers(input_array) {
                if (toString.call(input_array) !== "[object Array]")
                    return false;
                var r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
                var l = input_array.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    r1 = input_array[i] % input_array[i + 1];
                    if (r1 === 0) {
                        input_array[i + 1] = (input_array[i] * input_array[i + 1]) / input_array[i + 1];
                    }
                    else {
                        r2 = input_array[i + 1] % r1;
                        if (r2 === 0) {
                            input_array[i + 1] = (input_array[i] * input_array[i + 1]) / r1;
                        }
                        else {
                            input_array[i + 1] = (input_array[i] * input_array[i + 1]) / r2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return input_array[l - 1];
            }

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lcm_more_than_two_numbers(arr);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a side note unless you want to support IE <= 8 you should use Array.isArray(input_array) to check whether your input is an array.

Comment: For those testing, [OEIS A003418](http://oeis.org/A003418) defines the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was a hard bug to track, what a strange algorithm!
In your second else, you shouldn't divide by r2 :

```
input_array[i + 1] = (input_array[i] * input_array[i + 1]) / r2;
```

should be

```
input_array[i + 1] = input_array[i] * input_array[i + 1];
```

I found that by displaying `r1`, `r2` and `input_array[i+1]` at each loop and noticed that only values where `r2 > 1` were wrong (by the way you missed `lcm(1..7)` which was 140 and should have been 420). I then noticed that the expected result was the obtained result multiplied by `r2`.

Edit : Nope, still broken for at least 27 & 28. Just an algorithm masquerading pretty well for LCM.

Comment: Nice job, detective! Thanks for helping be find that bug. Time to squash it.

Comment: @nerdpire Err, the results for 27 and 28 are not due to number precision. Were did you get this algorithm seriously? I'm afraid it's just masquerading as lcm

Comment: @nerdpire never heard of that site, and I wouldn't trust too much a website tutorial on somewhat advanced algebra. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) and [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) give a lot of different algorithm but I didn't see any matching theirs.

Comment: I rewrote it. Tell me what you think:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The + Operator</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>

  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get your Answer!</button>

    <script>

 function myFunction() {
            var number = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

  var lowEnd = 1;
            var highEnd = number;
            var arr = [];
            while (lowEnd <= highEnd) {
                arr.push(lowEnd++);
            }

Comment: function LCM(A) 
{   
    var n = A.length, a = Math.abs(A[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
     { var b = Math.abs(A[i]), c = a;
       while (a && b){ a > b ? a %= b : b %= a; } 
       a = Math.abs(c*A[i])/(a+b);
     }
    return a;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = LCM(arr);

}

    </script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: I think that's a little too much code for comments ;) Could you instead provide a link to an online interpret like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: looks like its not working anyways. I'll send it anyways.

Comment: Heh, I've got no account, I expected a saved script rather than an interactive session, if it's no bother to you

Comment: I'm new to jsfiddle. Let me resend it.

Comment: It starts messing up at 44.

Comment: That might very well be a number precision problem this time. Can you tell me what result you are expecting? By the way, here's a cleaned up version of your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ftthwqs8/1/

Comment: Since 44 = 4*11, that means that the lcm of all numbers up to 44 should be the same of the lcm of all numbers up to 43, 103615469746826640000.

Comment: @nerdpire yup, "Javascript numbers larger than 9007199254740992 and smaller than -9007199254740992 are not precisely represented numbers and will not produce exact results" extract from [BigInteger.js' doc](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) which I will recommend if you need precise results for your algo.

Comment: Sorry, I copyed wrong, it should be 9419588158802422000.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you. Javascript noob here.

Comment: No problem, it's not like I had the number in mind. Btw you'll notice that BigInteger has a `lcm(a,b)` method, so you could just chain calls in a recursive fashion.

Comment: Here's a [working fiddle with bigInt](http://jsfiddle.net/ftthwqs8/3/) ! I tested it for 44 and it returns the expected value :)

Comment: Thank you very very very very very very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. I may have talked too fast however, it returns 9419588158802421600 rather than the number you mentionned earlier.

Comment: Let me check something. I was coping it from the code itself before it was fixed. I didn't know if it was right or not.

Comment: I checked. Turns out the program you sent is the one thats right.

Comment: Nice, glad I could help you !